# Configure a .tk domain on Zymic?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, configuration

I created a site on Zymic but I can not put my `.tk` domain, someone could help me solve this problem?

Comment: You should give us more information. What exactly doesn't work ?

Comment: I can not enter my .tk domain on Zymic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you will be getting is something like:

`You have entered an invalid TLD for your extra domain. Note that if you are using a subdomain, your fully qualified domain name will be your user name, plus the TLD of this site.`

A .TK domain is not a [TLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) (top level domain) but rather a [ccTLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain):

> [SOURCE:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.tk)
>
> .tk is the Internet country code top-level domain (ccTLD) for Tokelau, a territory of New Zealand located in the South Pacific.

You are not the only one to mention this and I recommend you [search their forums for similar problems reported by their users](http://www.zymic.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=12971&hl=cctld). Take from their sales page and as you can see no mention of ccTLD domains.

> [SOURCE](http://www.zymic.com/free-web-hosting/)
>
> Sub-Domains
>
> Yes A range of choices such as 99k.org, zxq.net, zymichost.com
>
> TLD Domain
>
> You can use your own domain on our hosting

If you want a host that supports everything pay for it. I recommend you check out our page about [how to find a web host company that meets my needs](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements).